# Need help with MVC route when i jQuery AJAX call a route

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm trying to access a simple ASP.NET MVC route, but it's erroring with:

> The parameters dictionary contains a
>   null entry for parameter
>   'isFoo' of non-nullable type
>   'System.Boolean' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Transform(Boolean, System.String)' in
>   .. blah blah blah.

Ie. the boolean property is not getting set ... which means the value is not getting passed in.

So i've got an Action method called Transform(..) and it's not accepting the values that are HTTP-Posted to it, with jQuery. It's like my posted values get lost :(

The MVC site is a stock standard ASP.NET MVC File->New->MVC Web Application. Nothing has been changed, with the exception of adding a new controller class. that's it.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

namespace WorldDomination.EbonHawk.Web.Controllers
{
    public class AjaxController : Controller
    {
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Transform(bool isFoo, string bar)
        {
            // blah....
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

and how this is called, using jQuery ....

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/transform",
    data: "isfoo=true&bar=" + $("#Bar").val(),
    contentType: "application/json;",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() { alert("it worked"); },
    failure: function() { alert("Uh oh"); }
});
```

When i use FireBug, it definately shows that i'm trying to POST to the url. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, it appears that you are confusing jQuery...

You are telling it that your data type is JSON, but submitting text.  Remove your dataType clause from your AJAX post, and jQuery will figure out and submit your post appropriately.

Comment: i thought the contentType: "application/json;" and dataType: "json" was what i EXPECTED to be returned from the server?

Comment: Actually, I think you're right.  You still need to send your data as JSON, though.

Comment: The error was that i should NOT have the contentType: "application/json;" value. That implies the format of the POST data being sent across the wire. the DataType: "json" is required if i'm wanting the results to be json.

Comment: I just had the same problem. I copied my jQuery code from a working WebForms app and it did not work for some reason. After removing the contentType parameter it works. I guess the params are matched with method parameters differently.

Answer (score 1):

What Jeff said. Alternatively, if you wish to keep the `dataType`, your `data` line should look like this:

```
...
data: { isfoo: true, bar: $("#Bar").val() },
...
```

Comment: if i do that, what does the controller action method look like?

Comment: transform(boolean isfoo,string bar)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC controller actions simply translate the POST or GET parameters into arguments to your function.  If the arguments are being passed correctly using one of those HTTP methods, you should be fine.  However, it seems you jQuery isn't working correctly.

You should change your $.ajax call to as follows

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<%= Url.Action("Transform", "Ajax") %>",
    data: { isfoo: true, bar: $("#Bar").val() },
    contentType: "application/json;",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() { alert("it worked"); },
    failure: function() { alert("Uh oh"); }
});
```

Note that this problem has nothing to do with the routing system.  If you wanted to use routing to make a clean URL to call using parameters, you would need to change your method to POST.  Overall, the way you have it right now is much cleaner, though.  It would be good, however, to use the routing system to generate the base URL for your service.

**EDIT:**

If you were to use GET parameters like you were in the data option, you would also need to make isfoo= read isFoo=, I think.  I can't remember if caps matter when parameterizing.

Comment: Agreed that i should change my code to "<%= Url.Action("Transform", Ajax") %>. BUT i need to make it a POST because the #Bar value can be _really really_ long.

Because u made the contentType: "app/json", is that why u had to format the data into: { key: value, key: value } ?